# Parse Server Migration request.installationId

Tags: parse-platform

Am i migrating a working Parse app.

I use request.installationId on both before and after save events to load the installation object (session) of the acting user as we have some metadata attached to it.

On my migrated app. This seems to be causing an issue. The request.installationId is returning a different uuid on the before and after event. The after event is correct the before is incorrect.

Is this no longer reliable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the error was caused by not properly passing the users session token with each API call. When migrating to Parse Server from the old hosted parse platform now closed. You need to adapt all of your cloud based api calls for querys, stored procedure calls to include either a users session or the flag to run the call with the master key.

```
 // calling a stored function, note the session token is passed in;
 return Parse.Cloud.run('getUserRole', data, {
    sessionToken: request.user.getSessionToken()
});
// If you want to run using the master key
return Parse.Cloud.run('getUserRole', data, {
   useMasterKey: true
});
```